# Why Quantlib CreditDefaultSwap::ISDA fail on roll dates: 1st iteration: failed at 1st alive instrument, pillar

Tags: quantlib, cds

I am experimenting with Quantlib CDS engine, I create a piecwise hzard rate based on CDSHelpers and try to compute default probability with it and then some specific upfront.

I managed to match BBG values on the few dates I tested, but when i tried the roll dates ie 19 March 2019 or 19 September 2019 I got the error below 
1st iteration: failed at 1st alive instrument, pillar June 21st, 2019, maturity June 21st, 2019, reference date March 19th, 2019: root not bracketed: f[2.22045e-16,1] -> [1.202135e-02,6.639330e+00]

This error happen only when I use CreditDefaultSwap::ISDA as a model while creating the cdshelpers, it doesn't occur if I use midPoint pricer.
But as it was mentioned in http://quantlib.10058.n7.nabble.com/Fail-to-replicate-ISDA-Fair-Value-CDS-Model-td18310.html
The midPoint pricer is unable to match the new standard calculation.

Also I probably should mention that this error happen only when I assume a 0 settelment days, but if I assume 1 day the curve I end up creating  use June's tenors (for a trade date of 19 march) instead of December's.

code:

````
    Date todaysDate(19, March, 2019);

    Settings::instance().evaluationDate() = todaysDate;
    .
    ./ create isdaRateHelper
    .
    Handle<YieldTermStructure> rateTs(
        ext::make_shared<PiecewiseYieldCurve<Discount, LogLinear> >(
            0, WeekendsOnly(), isdaRateHelper, Actual365Fixed()));
    CreditDefaultSwap::PricingModel model = CreditDefaultSwap::ISDA;
    std::vector<ext::shared_ptr<DefaultProbabilityHelper> > isdaCdsHelpers;
    std::vector<float> quotes={0.01202135, 0.01237659, 0.01290271, 0.01331895, 
    0.01375619, 0.01420986, 0.01425261, 0.01419832};
    std::vector<Period> periods{6 * Months,1 * Years,2 * Years,3 * Years,4 * 
        Years,5 * Years,7 * Years,10 * Years};
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<quotes.size();i++){
        ext::shared_ptr<CdsHelper> cds(new SpreadCdsHelper(
            quotes[i], periods[i], 0, WeekendsOnly(), Quarterly, Unadjusted,
            DateGeneration::CDS2015, Actual360(), 0.4, rateTs, true, true, todaysDate,Actual360(true), true,model));
        isdaCdsHelpers.push_back(cds);
    }
    ext::shared_ptr<PiecewiseDefaultCurve<HazardRate, BackwardFlat> > hazardRateStructure(new PiecewiseDefaultCurve<HazardRate, BackwardFlat>(todaysDate,isdaCdsHelpers, Actual365Fixed()));
    Handle<DefaultProbabilityTermStructure> isdaCts =  Handle<DefaultProbabilityTermStructure>(hazardRateStructure);

//check
    for(unsigned int i=0;i< hazardRateStructure->dates().size();i++)     
        cout<<hazardRateStructure->dates()[i]<<endl;
    std::cout << "default probability = " << isdaCts->DefaultProbability(Date(20,June,2019)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "default probability = " << isdaCts-defaultProbability(Date(20,June,2019)) << std::endl;
```
````

Comment: I would like to add that the dates returned by  in the hazard rate structure above are 21st of the month when we use model=CreditDefaultSwap::ISDA, I thought for unadjusted it should be 20th, it is 20th if we keep the same code and use MidPoint